# How to pass Go instances between Go and C functions?

Tags: go, cgo

I want to pass a Go instance as an argument to each call from C, like the code below.

I want to merely operate pointers to http.Client instances as opaque pointers in my C code.

I have a few questions.

- How to convert &http.Client to C type?
- How to prevent memory allocated by go from being freed?
- How to convert C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL type to &http.Client type?
- How to free memory allocated by go?

```c
typedef size_t HTTP_CLIENT_HDL

HTTP_CLIENT_HDL client_hdl = http_new_client();
int res = http_post(client_hdl, ...);
http_free_client(client_hdl);
```

```go
/*
typedef size_t HTTP_CLIENT_HDL; // correct type?
*/
import "C"
import (
    "net/http"
)

//export http_new_client
func http_new_client() (client_hdl C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL){
    client := &http.Client{
        ...
    }
    
    return C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL(client)    // Is correct?
                                        // How to prevent memory allocated to the client variable from being freed?
}

//export http_post
func http_post(client_hdl C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL, ...) (ret_val C.int) {
    client := &http.Client???(client_hdl)   // how to convert C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL to &http.Client?
    
    ...
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", ...)
    if err != nil {
        return 0
    }
    ...
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    ...
    
    return 1
}

//export http_free_client
func http_free_client(client_hdl C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL){
    client := &http.Client???(client_hdl)   // how to convert C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL type to &http.Client type?
    
    free???(client)     // how to free the memory for client ?
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to do with the client in c? You can't pass a complex struct like that and just use it in c. You can pass structs but they need to be composed of c compatible types and you need a type def in c.

Comment: You cannot do what you probably intend to do. That's simply not how computers work.

Comment: Do I assume correctly that you basically want to merely operate pointers to `http.Client` instances as _opaque pointers_ in your C code? That is, store them but not try to do with them anything _fancy_ other than passing them back to Go code? If yes, it's doable with some extra care on the Go part (which is not done in your code); otherwise the answer is no.

Comment: @kostix I want to merely operate pointers to http.Client instances as opaque pointers in my C code. So what extra code is needed to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Volker is correct: `cgo` rules dictate that you cannot pass to the C side pointers (references) to Go-allocated memory if that memory contains Go pointers (see [this](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo#hdr-Passing_pointers)). Well, the full ruleset is more complex but you'd better check the manual.

The rationale behind that is that even though no known contemporary implementation of Go employs *moving* garbage collector, the language spec does not preclude such implementation, which means the Go runtime powering your program must be able to know all the pointers to a particular Go-allocated memory chunk, and be able to *update* all of them if it so wishes.

So, a proper implementation would be to maintain a map of Go-allocated `*http.Client`s to some non-pointer "handles", and make the C code work with them–something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

/*
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
    #include <stdint.h>
    typedef uint64_t HTTP_CLIENT_HDL;
#else
    typedef unsigned long int HTTP_CLIENT_HDL;
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

HTTP_CLIENT_HDL http_new_client(void);
void http_free_client(HTTP_CLIENT_HDL);
char* http_post(HTTP_CLIENT_HDL, char*);

static int do_something(void) {
    HTTP_CLIENT_HDL h;
    char *err;
    int rc;

    h = http_new_client();

    err = http_post(h, "http://localhost:8080/");
    if (err != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
        free(err);
        rc = 0;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    rc = 1;
    printf("OK\n");

cleanup:
    http_free_client(h);

    return rc;
}
*/
import "C"

type httpClients struct {
    mu      sync.Mutex
    serial  C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL
    clients map[C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL]*http.Client
}

func (htc *httpClients) init() {
    htc.clients = make(map[C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL]*http.Client)
}

func (htc *httpClients) new() C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL {
    htc.mu.Lock()
    defer htc.mu.Unlock()

    c := &http.Client{}

    id := htc.serial
    htc.clients[id] = c
    htc.serial++

    return id
}

func (htc *httpClients) free(id C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL) {
    htc.mu.Lock()
    defer htc.mu.Unlock()

    delete(htc.clients, id)
}

func (htc *httpClients) get(id C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL) *http.Client {
    htc.mu.Lock()
    defer htc.mu.Unlock()

    c, ok := htc.clients[id]
    if !ok {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("no http client with id %d", id))
    }

    return c
}

var htClients httpClients

func init() {
    htClients.init()
}

//export http_new_client
func http_new_client() C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL {
    return htClients.new()
}

//export http_free_client
func http_free_client(h C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL) {
    htClients.free(h)
}

//export http_post
func http_post(h C.HTTP_CLIENT_HDL, url *C.char) *C.char {
    c := htClients.get(h)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", C.GoString(url), nil)
    if err != nil {
        return C.CString(err.Error())
    }

    _, err = c.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return C.CString(err.Error())
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    rc := C.do_something()
    if rc == 0 {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Note that this code is not particularly effective as each call to `http_*` functions goes through a mutex protecting the map of "handles" to `*http.Client`s.

---

On a side note: do you really need to allocate `http.Client`s? The `net/http` code is supposed to either work with the default client, `http.DefaultClient`, or with a single non-default instance, configured with particular parameters. IOW, you do not need to allocate a new `http.Client` to perform an HTTP request using `net/http`, so maybe you're solving a non-problem to begin with.